# mysql left join with count(on right table attribute) group by

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one with tags and another one with the actually selected tags of an article (table relation). I want to add the condition to select the **amount of the actually selected tags of the current article.** example selecting article 1:

```
--------------------------
| id | name   | selected |
--------------------------
| 0  | this   | 1        |
| 1  | is     | 0        | 
| 2  | sparta | 1        |
--------------------------
```

Ive got to this far:

```
SELECT t.*, count(t.id) as `selected`
FROM tag t LEFT JOIN relation r ON t.id = r.tid
GROUP BY t.id
```

table tag:

```
---------------
| id | name   |
---------------
| 0  | this   |
| 1  | is     |
| 2  | sparta |
---------------
```

table relation:

```
-------------
| tid | aid |
-------------
| 0   | 2   |
| 0   | 1   |
| 2   | 1   |
-------------
```

Comment: the problem is theres no condition checking if the aid equals the aid im searching for, and i dont know how to add it

Comment: WHERE r.aid='WHAT YOU ARE SEARCHING FOR' ?

Comment: ye but then i dont get ALL tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT : The first query returns the selected tags for an article and that's not the desired behaviour**

Is that the query you're looking for?

```
SELECT A.id
      , COUNT(T.id) AS [nb selected tags]
FROM article A
LEFT OUTER JOIN relation R ON R.aid = A.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tag T ON T.id = R.tid
                         AND T.selected = 1
GROUP BY A.id
```

Hope this will help you.

PS: If you just want the result of a specific Article, you juste have to add a `WHERE` clause before the `GROUP BY`.

---

**Query returning the desired data:**

```
SELECT T.id
     ,T.name
     , CASE
        WHEN R.tid IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END AS [selected]
FROM tag T
LEFT OUTER JOIN relation R ON R.tid = T.id
                            AND R.selected = 1
                            AND R.aid = ...
```

I assume that the table `relation`has a unicity on tid and aid.

Let me know if the query returns the expected result.

Comment: no, i want just to use the two tables without table article. and i want to select ALL tags and also check if the tag IS SELECTED. (look at the first table)

Comment: I updated my answer with a second query that will return the expected result. Hope this will help.

Comment: it didnt solve my problem but it helped me alot. Thank you alot. this is what ive been searching for:
SELECT t.*, CASE WHEN r.aid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `selected`
FROM tag t LEFT JOIN relation r ON t.id = r.tid
GROUP BY t.id

Comment: actually i need to add some more to my solution:
i also need to sum around the case: ... SUM(CASE WHEN r.aid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ...